# Distribution of number of events that occur a certain time between each other

Tags: probability, distributions, poisson-process

I'm modelling an experiment in which events happen homogenously (i.e., Poisson process).
The Poisson distribution models the distribution of the number of events that occur within $t$ of a particular point in time.

What distribution models the number of times, over a period of continual monitoring $T$, that two consecutive events occurred between $t_0$ and $t_1$ of each other?

Answer (score 2):

If $X_0$ is the time to the first event and $X_1$ is the additional time after that until the next event, and they are independent and exponential with mean $\lambda$, then $P[X_0<t_0,X_1<t_1]=(1-e^{-\lambda t_0})(1-e^{-\lambda t_1})$.
It is one type of bivariate exponential distribution.